# Change Codeigniter pagination query string

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I want to change codeigniter pagination query string. Currently this is working like below example

`http://example.com/1`

I want to change this with my example like

`http://example.com?page=1`

Anyone can let me know how I can do this without changes in existing library? or Should I have to create my own pagination for this system?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set config for [pagination](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/pagination.html)

```
$config['page_query_string'] to TRUE
```

you also can configure your querystring

```
$config['query_string_segment'] = 'your_string';
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually with [CodeIgniter 3.0.0](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/changelog.html#version-3-0-0) there is a better solution now;

You should enable the reusage of the query string buy enabling this configuration:

```
$config['reuse_query_string'] = true;
```

only after that you should initialize the pagination:

```
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using 'Enabling Query Strings' in `/application/config/config.php`

```
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
```

But, it will also add controller and method names as query stings not as clean urls like:

```
index.php?c=controller&m=method
```

[Reference](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html)

Comment: I have to make change only in pagination not in whole site.